# Only Add Certain Fields in Variable - Python Function - Django - Views

Tags: python, django, function, variables, field

I have Django model with CharFields 'flname1', 'date1', and 'time1'. **My goal** in my HTML is to have a {{ forloop }} that runs through only the 'date1' and 'time1' fields and displayed all of them. **My Problem** is that in my views file I can't find a way to create a python variable that only contains two of the three fields from one model. Ie tried a lot but what I'm trying to avoid is...

```
posts = DocPost.objects.all()
```

This puts all three fields into a variable and displays them in my for loop which I don't want. I've also tried a lot of work with filters and go things that other people on the internet had success with that didn't work for me like...

```
posts = DocPost.objects.filter('flname1').only('date1', 'time1')
```

This didn't work and didn't section off date1 and time1 and pack them away in a variable that I could loop through. Ive tried a lot more than this at this point to no prevail. Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do to only get certain fields in a query and iterate over them. The template for both is pretty much the same

First, you can use [only()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#only) to generate a queryset where each object only has certain fields populated and all the rest are [deferred](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer)

```
# View
context['posts'] = DocPost.objects.only('date1', 'time1')

# Template
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.date1 }}
    {{ post.time1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Second, you can use [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) to generate a queryset of dictionaries that only contain the fields specified

```
# View
context['posts'] = DocPost.objects.values('date1', 'time1')

# Template
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.date1 }}
    {{ post.time1 }}
{% endfor %}
```